# Density plot on the surface of a sphere

Tags: plotting

I would like to do it on the surface of a sphere instead of a plane:

```
RegionPlot[{1/
4 (-4 Sqrt[5]
    Cos[x]^2 + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (1 - 3 Cos[2 y]) Sin[
    x]^2 + (-5 - Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 + 
  4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Sin[2 x]) < -3, 1/4 (-4 Sqrt[5] Cos[x]^2 + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (1 - 3 Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 + (-5 - Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 + 4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Sin[2 x]) >= -3}, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> 0 , PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotPoints -> 35, PlotStyle -> {Red, Gray},   PlotLegends -> {"Contextual Region", "Classical Region"}]
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an alternative way.

```
SliceContourPlot3D[f[x, y], "CenterSphere", {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[# < 0, Red, Gray] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

If you like you can use `ContourStyle -> Opacity[0]`

```
SliceContourPlot3D[f[x, y], "CenterSphere", {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[# < 0, Red, Gray] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0], 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
rp = RegionPlot[{1/4 (-4 Sqrt[5] Cos[x]^2 + 
     (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (1 - 3 Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 +
     (-5 - Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 +
     4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Sin[2 x]) < -3, 
    1/4 (-4 Sqrt[5] Cos[x]^2 + 
     (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (1 - 3 Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 + 
     (-5 - Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 +
     4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Sin[2 x]) >= -3},
  {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, Frame -> False, ImagePadding -> 0, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotPoints -> 35, PlotStyle -> {Red, Gray}];

ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {v, 0, Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[Image @ rp], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#, #2} &), 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I may have misinterpreted the question. The x and y ranges suggest spherical coordinates. So, for the sake of clarification,:

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 1/4 (-4 Sqrt[
      5] Cos[x]^2 + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (1 - 3 Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 + (-5 -
        Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y]) Sin[x]^2 + 
    4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Sin[2 x])
p3 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, Mesh -> 10, ImageSize -> 200];
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 200];
max = NMaximize[f[x, y], {x, y}][[1]];
min = NMinimize[f[x, y], {x, y}][[1]];
rs = Rescale[f[#1, #2], {min, max}] &;
tab = Transpose@
   Table[{Hue[Rescale[j, {min, max}]], j}, {j, min, max, 0.1}];
pp = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, 0, 
    Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[rs[#4, #5]] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
   Mesh -> {10, 10}, MeshStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Black}], 
   PlotPoints -> 200, 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{tab[[1]], {min, max}}, tab[[2]]], 
   ImageSize -> 200];
Row[{cp, p3, pp}]
```

[image]

**Update**
Further answer in relation to comment:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, 0, 
  Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[f[#4, #5] < -3, Red, Gray] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, 
 Boxed -> False, Background -> Black, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 ImageSize -> 200]
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, Contours -> {-3}, 
 ContourShading -> {Red, Gray}]
```

[image]

**Update**

Further to another comment. The PlotPoints have been reduced to facilitate interactivity (further reductions reduce quality of plot).

```
Manipulate[Module[{pp =
    ParametricPlot3D[s[u, v], {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     ColorFunction -> (If[f[#4, #5] < -3, Red, Gray] &), 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, 
     Boxed -> False, Background -> Black, PlotPoints -> 75, 
     ImageSize -> 200], cp},
  Row[{ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     Contours -> {-3}, ContourShading -> {Red, Gray}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[0.04], Point[pt]}, ImageSize -> 200],
    Show[pp, 
     Graphics3D[{Yellow, PointSize[.04], 
       Point[s @@ pt]}]]}]], {{pt, {Pi/2, Pi}}, {0, 0}, {Pi, 2 Pi}}, 
 Initialization :> (f[x_, y_] := 
    1/4 (-4 Sqrt[
         5] Cos[x]^2 + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (1 - 3 Cos[2 y]) Sin[
          x]^2 + (-5 - Sqrt[5] + (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[2 y]) Sin[
          x]^2 + 4 (-5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) Cos[y] Sin[2 x]);
   s[u_, v_] := {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]};)]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, x and y are spherical coordinates. What I'd really like to do is to see a region plot on the surface of a sphere. This plot should depend on x and y values. Coloring should include two colors depending on whether the function is above or below -3.

Comment: @FiratDiker I plotted this like this to show the contours and how they ‘fold’ onto sphere. The show different regions compared with the provided answers. I’ll post your requirement when I have time.

Comment: May I show a specific point on the sphere?

Comment: Yes. You can combined with Graphics3D using Show